# Declare Swing View in XML

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, mvvm

I am working on a Swing application and would really love to declare my views in an XML format  in fashion similar to [GWT's UiBinder](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder), JSP, JSF, ZK, IceFaces, etc.

I found [JFCML](http://jfcml.sourceforge.net/) but it doesn't appear to be an active project; in terms of development as well as use/reference.

Have my Google skills failed me or does something like this not exist? If it doesn't exist, is it because such methods of separating view and controller are better done another way in Swing?

Comment: I also couldn't find anything; needed production quality.  Except some support in IDEs, Swing doesn't seem to have much attention.  We ended up extending an existing system manually.

Comment: You might want to check out Apache Pivot.  http://pivot.apache.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "built-in" solution is the [XMLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html) - [XMLDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/XMLDecoder.html) pair, but they are not widely used, I am not sure that they can cope with real-world scenarios.

A lot of open-source libraries have been suggested already on SO, I recommend these questions:

[suggestions for declarative GUI programming in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761237/suggestions-for-declarative-gui-programming-in-java)

[Java: Create a GUI with XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213838/java-create-a-gui-with-xml)

[Is XML or XUL the future of Java GUI building?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915810/is-xml-or-xul-the-future-of-java-gui-building)

[Java form from xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608296/java-form-from-xml)

Comment: Great, I missed that first one which looks like a good discussion. Cheers.